# html file does not appear after logging without any error

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, sendfile, serving

I am new to server-side programming.
I am trying to serve a HTML file (mapview.html) after authentication ,but **it** **does not appear** **without any error**.
there is no problem with authentication process. I expect when I click on login button, the codes check req data
and after validating, mapview.html pop up **but nothing happen.** 
res.sendFile() causes in jquery part, console.log(res), get me all html codes in console line of chrome.

---

files directory:

```
src
 index.js
 db 
 public 
   index.html
   mapview.html
 middleware 
   auth.js
 routers 
   user
   task
 model
   user
   task
```

---

index.html

```
  $('div[name="logIn"]').click( () => { // select a div element that its name is logIn
      console.log('LOG-IN:')                 

      $.ajax({
           url: '/login',
           data: $('#loginForm').serialize(), // Get email and pass from login form 
           type: 'POST',
           success: function (res) {                                      
                console.log(res)                       
           }   
      })

  })
```

---

user.js

```
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {

  try {
    const user = await User.findByCredentials(req.body.email, req.body.password)
    const token = await user.generateAuthToken()        

    const publicDir = path.join(__dirname, '../public')          
    res.sendFile(path.join(publicDir + '/mapview.html'));

  } catch (e) {         
     res.status(400).send(e)
  }
})
```

---

index.js

```
 const express = require('express');
 require('./db/mongoose'); 
 const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 const userRouter = require('./routers/user');
 const taskRouter = require('./routers/task');  

 const app = express();
 const port = process.env.PORT || 3000; 

 app.use(express.json()); // Parse recieved json body  data from Postman

 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));  

 app.use(userRouter); 
 app.use(taskRouter);   

 app.listen(port, () => {
   console.log('server is run on port:' + port)
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you are making the HTTP post request from index.html using ajax to verify user authentication details, on successful authentication you are sending a static html file which is simply a text response and will not be rendered as a web page (as you were expecting).

To solve this problem,

1. Create a separate route for accessing the mapview.html

```
    app.get('/map', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public' + '/mapview.html');
    });
```

2. In your ajax response just redirect to the map route

```
    $.ajax({
    url: '/login',
    data: $('#loginForm').serialize(), // Get email and pass from login form 
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (res) {                                      
        console.log(res);
        window.location.href = '/map';  // redirect to map route   
        }   
    });
```

Comment: the problem is app.get('/map', (req, res) is available easily and it should have authentication so I changed it to  router.get('/map', auth, (req, res). but I need somehow attach token to window.location.heref='/map'  . token already send back to localstorage and i can easily get it but i do not know how attach it to .href='/map'

Comment: It is not possible to attach auth token in window.location.href. But you can make use of sessions to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the codes and it looks like following code .
As I mention in the past comment , I need to authenticate before refirect through .href = '/map' and **I do not know how to attach token to .href='/map**. 
we usually send token as header with ajax like this: 
    headers:{"Authorization": localStorage.getItem('token')}

in case I add it to .href ,something like this  window.location.href = '/map + "?token=MY_TOKEN" , how can i get it in auth method?

---

user.js

```
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {

  try {
     const user = await User.findByCredentials(req.body.email, 
         req.body.password)
     const token = await user.generateAuthToken()        
     res.send({user, token})        

   } catch (e) {
     res.send(e)
     res.status(400).send(e)
   }
 })

 router.get('/map', auth, (req, res) => {
   const publicDir = path.join(__dirname, '../public') 
   res.sendFile(path.join(publicDir + '/mapview.html'));     
 });
```

---

index.html

```
         $('div[name="logIn"]').click( () => {                  
            $.ajax({
               url: '/login',
               data: $('#loginForm').serialize(),  
               type: 'POST',
               success: function (res) { 
                  localStorage.setItem('token', res.token);    
                  window.location.href = '/map';     
               }                       
            }) 
        })
```

Comment: the problem solved.. to whom might encounter with this problem i could get the token through req._parsedOriginalUrl.query .. and that worked ...